# How to store securely the username and password used to authenticate to the config server on-premise?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices, spring-boot-actuator

I'm new to the spring cloud config server. We are trying to set up a spring cloud config server on-premise.
The application can connect to the spring cloud config server using the below property and value.

```
spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http://root:s3cr3t@localhost:8088
```

However, I'm not sure how to secure the username and password used to connect to the spring cloud config server.
Right now, the username and password are in the application.properties file.

What are the best practices to store them?

Can I store them as environment variables?

Answer (score 0):

You can store such credentials safely in value, [Harshi](https://www.vaultproject.io/) preferably. Alternatively if deployed on k8s, k8s secrets is useful feature.

Comment: Can't I store them as environment variables? The application is on-premise.

Comment: @SwetaSharma: environment variables are ephemeral. *Something* needs to store the value to re-set the environment variable every time. There are existing tools (infrastructure, really) that handles this complicated issue. Your "can't we simply" solution was probably found to be lacking in some respect. It's not a trivial issue and any organization that handles any secrets in their running code (i.e. almost everyone running code on servers) needs to tackle this eventually.

Comment: yes you can store credentials as environment variables if it suits. do keep in mind abt suggestions by @JoachimSauer

Answer (score 0):

Storing credentials in unencrypted files is NOT considered a good practice. One way that I would recommend is to store sensible data in an encrypted file(with a symmetric algorithm like AES 256).

You can decrypt the file at the start time of your app, by entering the secret password used to derive the key of the encryption algorithm.

You could store the credentials in environmental variables on your system, but that would just move the problem in another place. Anybody with access on your systems could see this variables. The MOST SECURE way is to use encryption based on a secret that only you know.